# Error al compilar con Pyinstaller la libreria pyzbar: Failed execute script 'main' due to unhandle exception: Failed to load dynlib/dll

Tags: python, imagen

Tendo el siguiente error cada que intento abrir el ejecutable que compile mediante pyinstaller: **Failed execute script 'main' due to unhandle exception: Failed to load dynlib/dll.**

Este error solo aparece en ejecutable, al correr el script directamente desde el IDE funciona correctamente. Este error aparece al usar el siguiente fragmento de codigo que utilizo para leer el codigo de barras en una imagen:

```
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
    def lectura_imagen(_imagen_):
        try:
            lectura = decode(_imagen_)
            print(lectura[0].data.decode('utf-8'))
            return True
        except:
            print('NO SE PUDO LEER LA IMAGEN')
            return False
```

[image: error]

Comment: Me suena a que ese dll no está incluyendose automaticamente en el exe. Lamentablemente, no se como debe modificarse el archivo de configuración (spec creo) para que incluya el dll. Pero espero esto ayude y suerte!